# SQL Implementing 'IN' operator with 'OR'

Tags: sql, oracle, operator-precedence

I am working on a legacy system which has a custom java implementation for generating SQL queries. That doesn't support 'IN' operation.
To implement 'IN' I have written something like

```
SELECT * from Q
WHERE IS_HIDDEN = 0 AND ID = 1 
OR ID = 2 OR ID = 3 AND IS_DELETED = 0;
```

I know that the one like below would have been fine.

```
SELECT * from Q
WHERE IS_HIDDEN = 0 AND (ID = 1  
OR ID = 2 OR ID = 3)  AND IS_DELETED = 0 ;
```

Both these return the same result but I'm not too confident about SQL operator priorities. I had read that AND takes precedence
Is it safe to assume that both the SQL statemets are equivalent.

The actual query that I wanted to write is

```
SELECT * from Q
WHERE IS_HIDDEN = 0 AND ID IN(1, 2, 3)  AND IS_DELETED = 0;
```

The DB in question is oracle 10g.

Update: The reason that this was working is because the oracle CBO rearranges the subclauses in the where clause.

Comment: what is your question? Your query with `IN` is right

Comment: The question is are the two queries same as the one with IN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No your queries are not the same

```
SELECT * from Q
WHERE IS_HIDDEN = 0 AND ID = 1 
OR ID = 2 OR ID = 3 AND IS_DELETED = 0;
```

is like

```
SELECT * FROM Q WHERE IS_HIDDEN = 0 AND ID = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Q WHERE ID = 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM Q WHERE ID = 3 AND IS_DELETED = 0
```

when you use the parentheses for your ORs then you have the same like the IN-Clause

You can try it: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/885f2/3)

Comment: On SQLFiddle the behavior is as you have described but on my local oracle db all the three are returning the same result.

Regardless I don't have confidence in pushing the existing query and I will look to extend the framework.

Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You first query is equal to the IN. You should use that:

Your second query is like this:

```
SELECT * from Q
WHERE (IS_HIDDEN = 0 AND ID = 1) OR ID = 2 OR (ID = 3 AND IS_DELETED = 0);
```

If IS_HIDDEN is 1 or DELETED Is 1, but ID is 2, your query will still give you records. Try it..

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. It looks like these aren't equivalent.